# Display Y Axis label below the Y Axis values on Kendo Charts

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a multi axis chart. I would like to display each Y Axis label below the Y-Axis values. Is this possible in Kendo?

[image]

Comment: you can only mirror the value axis label with https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/valueaxis.labels#valueAxis.labels.mirror, if u can put a draw of your desired layout

Comment: Just updated with demo image